# the docker official image hello-world keep reporting 'Back-off restarting failed container' with kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes

I keep seeing `Back-off restarting failed container` when try to use docker official image https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world to create any pod\deployment. When I switch to other images like `nginx` everything works well.

How can I debug and fix this issue?

Below are the event logs after creating the pod with `kubectl`.

```
root@ip-10-229-68-221:~# kubectl get event --watch
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                             MESSAGE
24s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Successfully assigned default/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv to kind-lab-worker
23s         Normal    Pulling             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Pulling image "hello-world:linux"
16s         Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Successfully pulled image "hello-world:linux" in 7.371731633s
1s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Started container hello-world
1s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
13s         Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
24s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Successfully assigned default/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs to kind-lab-worker
23s         Normal    Pulling             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Pulling image "hello-world:linux"
13s         Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Successfully pulled image "hello-world:linux" in 9.661065021s
13s         Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Created container hello-world
13s         Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Started container hello-world
13s         Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
11s         Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
24s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Successfully assigned default/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm to kind-lab-worker
23s         Normal    Pulling             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Pulling image "hello-world:linux"
18s         Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Successfully pulled image "hello-world:linux" in 5.17232683s
3s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Created container hello-world
2s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Started container hello-world
3s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
2s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
24s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/helloworld-656898b9bb   Created pod: helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm
24s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/helloworld-656898b9bb   Created pod: helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs
24s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/helloworld-656898b9bb   Created pod: helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv
24s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/helloworld              Scaled up replica set helloworld-656898b9bb to 3
79s         Normal    Killing             pod/nginx                          Stopping container nginx
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Started container hello-world
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Created container hello-world
1s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Started container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Started container hello-world
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Started container hello-world
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Started container hello-world
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Started container hello-world
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-98vrv    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-vhhfm    Back-off restarting failed container
0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Container image "hello-world:linux" already present on machine
0s          Normal    Created             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Created container hello-world
0s          Normal    Started             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Started container hello-world
0s          Warning   BackOff             pod/helloworld-656898b9bb-sg6fs    Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: both 'last' and 'linux' tag was tried and got same failure for the image

Answer (score 2):

`hello-world` image is not a long-running process: it just outputs text and stops.

Kubernetes Pod is by default expecting long-running processes, and if it stops it automatically restart the container.

This behavior is defined by the [`restartPolicy` parameter of a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) and can have different values:

- `Always`: always restart stopped container (the default)
- `OnFailure`: restart containers that exited with !=0
- `Never`: don't restart containers

So in your case you should use one of the 2 last as the container is expected to stop normally.